# Python - execute an instance?

Tags: python, class, function

Is it possible to execute an instance of a class? I don't mean instantiate a class, or execute a method. I mean something like a sibling to __string__ that would return a function. Let's call it __func__.

```
class ClassFunc (object):
    def __func__ (self):
        print "I'm a class!"

>>> myCF = ClassFunc()
>>> myCF()
I'm a class!
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Close. You want [`__call__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__).

Comment: Excellent. Thank you! (I promise I did search Google for a while, but I couldn't find the answer)

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> class ClassFunc (object):
        def __call__ (self):
            print "I'm a class!"


>>> myCF = ClassFunc()
>>> myCF()
I'm a class!
```